# Javadoc for StringUtils

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javadoc, string-utils

I've added a maven dependency for StringUtils (org.apache.commons.lang)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId></artifactId>
 <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to see javadoc of that jar , otherwise the javadoc for each functions in (org.apache.commons.lang) when I point the cursor in this function, is there some dependency for it?

Comment: yes Thanks it resolves my problem I've added    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following plugin which I use

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>false</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```